# Excluding <see cref="class"> xmldoc references from showing up in CodeLens?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense, codelens

Is there a way to prevent CodeLens from picking up on class references made in xmldoc comments?

I like that the cref tags make sure the spelling is correct, provide clickable links in the documentation, are picked up by refactoring etc., but I feel that it needlessly clutters up the codelens list of references.

Here is an image to illustrate what I mean:

[image: Unnecessary codelens reference]

Any ideas? This is VS2017 Pro with the latest Resharper beta, but also applies to VS2015 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no option to achieve your requirement. Usually to configure or to turn CodeLens off and on, you can go to Tools, Options, Text Editor, All Languages, CodeLens.

Since it is still a reference of class ‘EntityFrameworkContextTestConfiguration’ even if in xml document, add into the CodeLens-Reference is accepted. For your idea, I reported a user voice to the Visual Studio Product Team and you can check this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17960185-please-add-an-option-to-turn-off-codelens-referenc and vote it, then waiting for the response from the VS product team engineers.